# Monad trait in Scala

Tags: generics, scala, functional-programming

(How) is it possible to represent monads in Scala in a generic way (like the `Monad` typeclass in Haskell)? Is it somehow possible to define a `trait Monad` for this purpose?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
trait Monad[+M[_]] {
  def unit[A](a: A): M[A]
  def bind[A, B](m: M[A])(f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}

// probably only works in Scala 2.8
implicit def monadicSyntax[M[_], A](m: M[A])(implicit tc: Monad[M]) = new {
  private val bind = tc.bind(m) _

  def map[B](f: A => B) = bind(f compose tc.unit)

  def flatMap[B](f: A => M[B]) = bind(f)
}

implicit object MonadicOption extends Monad[Option] {
  def unit[A](a: A) = Some(a)

  def bind[A, B](opt: Option[A])(f: A => Option[B]) = opt flatMap f
}
```

You would of course define similar implicit objects for any other monad your heart desires.  In Haskell terms, you can think of `Monad` like the typeclass and `MonadicOption` as a particular instance of that type class.  The `monadicSyntax` implicit conversion simply demonstrates how this typeclass could be used to allow the use of Scala's `for`-comprehensions with anything which satisfies the `Monad` typeclass.

Generally speaking, most things in the Scala standard library which implement `flatMap` are monads.  Scala doesn't define a generic `Monad` typeclass (though that would be very useful).  Instead, it relies on a syntactic trick of the parser to allow the use of `for`-comprehensions with *anything* which implements the appropriate methods.  Specifically, those methods are `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` (or `foreach` and `filter` for the imperative form).

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I just wanted to define generic monad functions and transformers in a general way ...

Comment: You're not actually going to use this for anything real, are you?  :-)  Seriously, I've been working with Scala for a while, and I've found that a lot of cases where Haskell would use the Monad typeclass just don't come up in Scala because of traits and subtyping.  The typeclass given above, while cool, would certainly not be the idiomatic way to solve problems in Scala.

Comment: But they do come up. They come up all the time. A couple of times a day, I want `liftA2` or `sequenceA`. Granted, these only require Applicative rather than Monad, but still, if these don't come up in your programming then you must be writing something very simple.

Comment: It's possible that I'm just not watching closely enough for the cases as they come up.  Alternatively, I may be designing my code in such a way that other solutions work better.  Scala allows for object-functional solutions to problems which require heavy functional magic in languages like Haskell or ML (e.g. using open-recursion rather than functor tricks).

Comment: Of course it's real - Think of a monadic representation of an interpreter! It's awful without monadic abstraction!

Comment: Isn't Monad conceptually a container/context wherein the `unit` should take an object and return it in context of Monad. The `unit` method here is returning plain `Option` and not something like `Monad[option]`, is that correct?

Comment: @DanielSpiewak very useful! Some of the code didn't compile, so I had a go at getting it to compile and using it in an example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/k77LhapSSluBDEjo0uPsJA

Comment: @DanielSpiewak what does 'tc' stand for?

Comment: @DanielSpiewak I made a short slide deck based on this: https://www.slideshare.net/pjschwarz/abstracting-over-the-monad-yielded-by-a-for-comprehension-and-its-generators

Answer (score 15):

You may find the [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) project interesting; it has lots of other (functional) stuff as well besides an implementation of monads.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic.  A case class is already built into the language and used extensively throughout for collections...

Answer (score 4):

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/ruby/monads-are-not-metaphors

Here's a useful and rather lengthy article about the Monad pattern and its implementation in Scala by Daniel, who wrote the accepted answer for this question.

(For those who stumble upon this "ancient" question via the mystical ways of StackOverflow's site-search.)

Answer (score 2):

Scala achieves similar power to Haskell's type classes through use of implicit parameters, particularly view bounds and context bounds. You can see such things in use particularly on Scala 2.8, with traits like `Ordering` and `Numeric`.

That said, look at the [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) project. It has monads, functors, arrows... the whole shebang.