# Scala equivalent to Haskell monads

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, monads

I had some experience in Haskell and currently learning Scala. Am wondering whether there is something equivalent to Monads in Scala??

Comment: Did you consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992532/monad-trait-in-scala ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want to check out [**scalaz**](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/); it's been strongly influenced by Haskell. Indeed, it has often been asked of one of the prime contributors why they aren't *just* using Haskell, as they seem to like it so much!

Scalaz makes heavy use of implicits in order to decorate structures with their monads. For example:

```
val fibs = (0, 1).iterate[Stream]( i => i._2 -> (i._2 + i._1) ).map(_._1)
println( fibs.take(10) )
```

Comment: Actually the @VonC comment on my question gave me more details. But I can't accept that answer, also @oxbow_lakes showed me something new. Thank you guys for help

Comment: BTW: the authors of Scalaz *do* use Haskell. If you look at the sourcecode of Scalaz, you will see that they use Haskell for the build system instead of Ant, for example. Also, Tony Morris (the main author) *is* a pretty well known Hakell programmer. He is also the author of FunctionalJava, which is a library that implements Functors, Applicative Functors, Bifunctors, Monads, Comonads and Arrows for Java (just like Scalaz does for Scala). And as for why use Scala: Scala's type system and language is actually in several areas more powerful and expressive than Haskell's.

Comment: @Jorg - emphasis changed - I know Tony uses Haskell, I was implying that it had been asked as to exactly *why* he ever used scala!

Comment: That snippet looks awesome. But how to work it? There is no iterate function on Tuple2. I've included scalaz on the classpath, but still no joy.

Comment: Have a look at the scalaz examples. You need to import scalaz._ and be using 2.8. The Tuple2 is implicitly converted into the Identity monad

Comment: So you are using `->` as an alternative to writing something as a tuple? But the object on the left is a tuple written as a tuple? This seems inconsistent and made the code hard to read for me as I was expecting something like a `Map`.

Answer (score 9):

I think is worth noting that Scala's "for-comprehension" is equivalent to Haskell's monadic "do"

Answer (score 0):

Both Option and List are monads.  I also believe that Either's left and right projections are also monads.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit concept of monad in Scala standard library (there is no appropriate trait/class or typeclass).

Scala deals with this in kind of an ad-hoc manner, see [Scala by example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf)'s section on **for comprehensions** for details.