# Common practice for higher-order-polymorphism in scala

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, monads, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to grasp higher-order-polymophism in scala by implementing a very basic interface that describes a monad but I come across a problem that I don't really understand.

I implemented the same with C++ and the code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Value {
private:
  T value;
public:
  Value(const T& t) {
    this->value = t;
  }

  T get() {
    return this->value;
  }
};

template < template <typename> class Container >
class Monad {
public:
  template <typename A> Container<A> pure(const A& a); 
};

template <template <typename> class Container>
  template <typename A>
Container<A> Monad<Container>::pure(const A& a) {
  return Container<A>(a);
}

int main() {
  Monad<Value> m;
  std::cout << m.pure(1).get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When trying to do the same with scala I fail:

```
class Value[T](val value: T)

class Monad[Container[T]] {
  def pure[A](a: A): Container[A] =
    Container[A](a)
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    val m = new Monad[Value]
    m.pure(1)
  }
}
```

The compiler complains about:

```
[raichoo@lain:Scala]:434> scalac highorder.scala
highorder.scala:5: error: not found: value Container
    Container[A](a)
    ^
one error found
```

What am I doing wrong here? There seems to be a fundamental concept I don't seem to understand about scala typeconstructors.

Regards,
raichoo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992532/monad-trait-in-scala

Comment: Thanks, that link looks very interesting but does not really answer my question. I didn't want to know anything about monads, my question was about type constructor polymorphism. Even though, it looks like a good read. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Monad` trait in Scala would be declared as follows:

```
trait Monad[M[_]] {
  def pure[A](a: => A): M[A]
  def bind[A,B](a: M[A], f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

Note that it's parameterized with a type constructor `M[_]`. The bracketed underscore indicates that `M` is a type constructor of *kind* `(* -> *)` (i.e. `M` takes some type `A` to construct a type `M[A]`). Your identity monad instance would then be written like this:

```
class Value[A](a: => A) { lazy val value = a }

implicit val identityMonad = new Monad[Value] {
  def pure[A](a: => A) = new Value(a)
  def bind[A,B](a: Value[A], f: A => Value[B]) = new Value(f(a.value).value)
}
```

This definition uses by-name parameters to achieve lazy semantics.

Monad and other useful higher-kinded type classes are provided by the [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) library along with a lot of instances for the standard Java/Scala libraries.

Comment: Amazing, my head just exploded, but that was what I have been searching for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

If you change your definition of the `Monad` class to the following

```
class Monad[Container[_]] {        
  def pure[A <% Container[A]](a: A): Container[A] = a
}
```

The syntax `Container[_]` is how higher kinds are expressed in Scala. The `A <% Container[A]` is a 'view bound' that expresses that `A` is implicitly convertible to `Container[A]`. The body of the method uses this implicit conversion.  To use this class, you need to have an implicit conversion in scope for (in your example) `Int` to `Value[Int]`

```
implicit def toValue[T](t:T) = new Value(t)
```

You can then do the following

```
scala> val m = new Monad[Value]                     
m: Monad[Value] = Monad@781fb069

scala> m.pure(1).value         
res3: Int = 1
```

Comment: Sorry Container[_] is not a higher kinded type in Scala like I just learned in [what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what would be the best solution, but in the definition of pure in your code:

```
class Monad[Container[T]] {
  def pure[A](a: A): Container[A] = Container[A](a)
}
```

What `Container[A](a)` should do? So far, you've defined Container as a generic type XXX and you don't  have any information on how to build a new object. You need to pass a "builder" object as implicit parameter.
Take a look at how the collection libraries are implemented in Scala 2.8 or the Monad definition in Scalaz