# Incomprehensible syntax in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax

I have the following code that I found in this article (http://hseeberger.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/introduction-to-category-theory-in-scala/).

```
trait GenericCategory[->>[_, _]] {
  def id[A]: A ->> A
  def compose[A, B, C](g: B ->> C, f: A ->> B): A ->> C
}
```

I can't figure out the syntax right next to the trait's name

```
[->>[_,_]]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Scala type parameters, what do ->> and ->>> mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050107/in-scala-type-parameters-what-do-and-mean)

Comment: As with methods of a single argument, generic types / type constructors of two arguments can be used in infix form. That probably makes the name a bit more sensible, since it is presumably meant to be used that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [higher-kinded type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala), described nicely in [this introduction](http://wiki.ifs.hsr.ch/SemProgAnTr/files/HigherKindGenericsInScala.pdf) and in this [research paper](http://adriaanm.github.io/files/higher.pdf).

The reason you might find it confusing is that `->>` is the name for the higher-kinded type -- it might have as well been called `Arrow` instead.

Comment: Great references, would you mind to add this same answer to the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050107/in-scala-type-parameters-what-do-and-mean) referred to by @om-nom-nom?