# What is a "kind" in the context of Type Systems?

Tags: scala, types, higher-kinded-types, type-constructor

I have already read the Wikipedia article and searched for obvious places but I'm stuck. Can someone simple tell me what exactly is a Kind ? What is it used for ?

Scala examples are most appreciated

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short: a *kind* is to *types* what a *type* is to *values*.

What is a *value*? `1`, `2`, `3` are values. So are `"Hello"` and `"World"`, `true` and `false`, and so forth.

Values belong to *types*. Types describe a set of values. `1`, `2` and `3` belong to the type `Nat`, `"Hello"` and `"World"` to the type `Text`, `true` and `false` to the type `Boolean`.

*Functions* take one or more values as arguments and produce one or more values as results. In order to meaningfully do something with the arguments, the function needs to make some assumptions about them, this is done by constraining their types. So, function parameters and return values typically also have types.

Now, a function also has a type, which is described by the types of its inputs and outputs. For example, the `abs` function which computes the absolute value of a number has the type

```
Number -> NonNegativeNumber
```

The function `add` which adds two numbers has the type

```
(Number, Number) -> Number
```

The function `divmod` has the type

```
(Number, Number) -> (Number, Number)
```

Okay, but if functions take values as arguments and produce values as results, and functions are values, then functions can also take functions as arguments and return functions as results, right? What's the type of such a function?

Let's say we have a function `findCrossing` which finds the point where some other function (of numbers) crosses the y-axis. It takes as an argument the function and produces as a result a number:

```
(Number -> Number) -> Number
```

Or a function `makeAdder` which produces a function which takes a number and adds a specific number to it:

```
Number -> (Number -> Number)
```

And a function which computes the derivative of another function:

```
(Number -> Number) -> (Number -> Number)
```

Let's look at the level of abstraction here: a value is something very concrete. It only means one thing. If we were to order our levels of abstraction here, we could say that a value has the order 0.

A function, OTOH is more abstract: a single function can produce many different values. So, it has order 1.

A function which returns or accepts a function is even more abstract: it can produce many different functions which can produce many different values. It has order 2.

Generally, we call everything with an order > 1 "*higher order*".

Okay, but what about *kinds*? Well, we said above that `1`, `2`, `"Hello"`, `false` etc. have types. But what is the type of `Number`? Or `Text`? Or `Boolean`?

Well, its type is `Type`, of course! This "type of a type" is called a *kind*.

And just like we can have functions which construct values out of values, we can have functions which construct types out of types. These functions are called *type constructors*.

And just like functions have types, type constructors have kinds. For example, the `List` type constructor, which takes an element type and produces a list type for that element has kind

```
Type -> Type
```

The `Map` type constructor, which takes a key type and a value type and produces a map type has kind

```
(Type, Type) -> Type
```

Now, continuing the analogy, if we can have functions which take functions as arguments, can we also have type constructors which take type constructors as arguments? Of course!

An example is the `Functor` type constructor. It takes a type constructor and produces a type:

```
(Type -> Type) -> Type
```

Notice how we always write `Type` here? Above, we had many different types like `Number`, `Text`, `Boolean` etc. Here, we *always* have only kind of type, namely `Type`. That gets tedious to (warning, bad pun ahead) type, so instead of writing `Type` everywhere, we just write `*`. I.e. `Functor` has the kind

```
(* -> *) -> *
```

and `Number` has the kind

```
*
```

Continuing the analogy, `Number`, `Text` and all others of kind `*` have order 0, `List` and all others of kind `* -> *` or more generally `(*, …) -> (*, …)` have order 1, `Functor` and all of kind `(* -> *) -> *` or `* -> (* -> *)` (and so forth) have order 2. Except in this case we sometimes also call it *rank* instead of order.

Everything above order/rank 1 is called *higher-order*, *higher-rank* or *higher-kinded*.

I hope the analogy is clear now: types describe sets of values; kinds describe sets of types.

---

Aside: I completely ignored currying. Basically, currying means that you can transform any function which takes two values into a function which takes one value and returns a function which takes the other value, similarly for three, four, five, … arguments. This means that you only ever need to deal with functions with exactly one parameter, which makes languages much simpler.

However, this also means that technically speaking, `add` is a higher-order function (because it returns a function) which is muddying the definitions.

Comment: Quoted you in my answer. Well, basically because it's the essence. Hope it's ok with you.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of answer I don't wanna hear ;)

Comment: I *swear* I did not watch the video before writing this!

Comment: WOW! You did expand your answer!

Comment: About the video, I did knew it before watching the video too, I just didn't had all the knowledge to state it out loud as Daniel had.

Comment: Very nice. I think my problem was with the meaning of "Higher Order" from the beginnings. Just a suggestion, wouldn't it be clarifying if you explained in your answer that fully applied constructors are "proper" ? I spend a good time realizing 
`Map[String,Int]` is a proper type but `Map[A,B]` is a type constructor, the difference being the former is a fully applied constructor but the later is parametric. Who knows we may even turn it into a community wiki or whatever ...

Answer (score 5):

The most eloquent explanation for kinds/higher-kinds I've seen so far and also in the context of Scala is [Daniel Spiewak's High Wizardry in the Land of Scala](http://vimeo.com/28793245). There are many versions, he gave this talk a few times, here I've chosen the longest one, but you can quickly google and find others.

The most important message from this talk is exactly the answer given by @Jörg W Mittag:

"kind is to types what a type is to values"

Another place for a more theoretical view on the subject is the paper [Generics of a Higher Kind](http://adriaanm.github.com/files/higher.pdf), also in the context of Scala.