# What is a unary type?

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types, type-constructor

I am going through [Higher-kinded types & ad-hoc polymorphism](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#higher) section of twitter's Scala School and I don't understand and can't find reference anywhere to a *unary type*. Here is the context of the usage:

> For example, whereas “**unary types**” have constructors
>   like `List[A]`, meaning we have to satisfy one “level” of type variables
>   in order to produce a concrete types (just like an uncurried function
>   needs to be supplied by only one argument list to be invoked), a
>   higher-kinded type

Comment: AFAIK it is not an official term. Think of it as of unary function in the type space, a type that has one type argument, like List.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean by type space?

Comment: The set or collection or category of Scala types, name it as you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That statement doesn't really make sense.

First off, there is no such thing as a "unary type". Types don't have parameters, so that just doesn't make sense.

There *are* "unary type **constructors**", i.e. type constructors which have one parameter, such as `List[A]`. But the statement implies that all type constructors which *aren't* unary are higher-kinded, and that is simply not true. For example, `Either[A, B]` is *binary* (it has two parameters), but it is not higher-kinded.

A type constructor which has a type **constructor** as its parameter or a type constructor which returns a type **constructor** as its result, *that* is a higher-kinded type constructor. Just like a function with two arguments is not automatically higher-order, only a function which has a function parameter or returns a function is. (Note: in some branches of mathematics, functions are called "value constructors", which is actually where the name "type constructor" comes from, because just like a function takes values and produces values, a type constructor takes types and produces types; a type constructor is kind-of like a function on the type level.)

There is one wrinkle here, and it is the same as with functions: when we assume that *all* type constructors are unary, then we need to use currying to represent type constructors with more than one parameter, and in *that* sense (and *only* in that sense!) all non-unary type constructors are automatically also higher-kinded type constructors. Again, this is just like functions: `add` is by no means a higher-order function, but if we use currying, then we represent it as a function which takes one integer and returns a function that takes a second integer and returns an integer, which technically makes it a higher-order function.

But that is not the case in Scala: Scala *can* represent type constructors with multiple parameters without the use of currying, so non-unary type constructors are not automatically higher-kinded.

Kinds are notated similar to types, except we simple write `*` instead of `Type`, because it conveys no information: type constructors always operate on types, there is no need to type `Type` everywhere. So, a unary type constructor like `List` has kind:

```
* → *
```

A binary type constructor like `Either` has kind:

```
(*, *) → *
```

When you are forced to represent it using currying because your language only allows a single type parameter, then the kind of `Either` becomes:

```
* →  * → *  // `→` is right-associative just as with function types, so this is 
* → (* → *) // which is higher-kinded
```

The `Container` type constructor from the page you linked has kind:

```
Container :: (* → *) → *
```

So, it takes a type constructor as an argument and returns a type. And that is what makes it *higher-kinded*. In fact, you will note that `Container` actually is unary! It only takes a single argument. So, the statement actually contains a counter example to its own claim. (And again, this is similar to functions. E.g. the `fix` function in the Haskell prelude is higher-order, but unary: it takes only one argument, but that argument is a function.)

The reason why this is pointed out specifically in that description is that this is not true of some other mainstream languages in the field of typed OO languages like Java or C♯. Both Java and C♯ do not allow type constructors as parameters or results of type constructors. You can only pass a type to a type constructor, and the result of a type constructor is always a type. Both Java and C♯ do not support higher-kinded types. This makes Scala somewhat special in that regard, and that is why it is pointed out specifically on that page. (Of course, in the field of typed functional languages, higher-kindedness is nothing special.)

**tl;dr** summary:

- there is no such thing as a "unary type"
- the statement conflates arity of type constructors (the number of parameters) with higher-kindedness (whether the parameters and/or results are types or type constructors)
- non-unary type constructors are not necessarily higer-kinded, e.g. `Either[A] :: (*, *) → *`
- higher-kinded type constructors can be unary, e.g. `Container :: (* → *) → *`

---

There is some more information in this older answer of mine: [*What is a “kind” in the context of Type Systems?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12339025/2988).

Comment: But `* → * → *` is `* → (* → *)` which is higher-kinded (in result kind, not argument kind).

Comment: Yes, like I wrote: once you restrict yourself to have *only* unary type constructors and use currying to represent non-unary type constructors, then *all* non-unary type constructors become higher-kinded *by definition*. But they are "higher-kinded* in the same sense that adding two numbers is a "higher-order function": it is a consequence of artificially restricting the arity to always be exactly 1.

Comment: I would maybe call that "artificial higer-kindedness"? I don't know, is there a term for that? Again, it is easier to talk about this in terms of functions, because that's what people are probably more familiar with: in Scala, `add` has type `(Int, Int) → Int`, because Scala allows more than one argument. In Haskell, `add` has type `Int → ( Int → Int)`, simply because there is no other way to represent it. (Well, you could use a 2-tuple instead, of course, thus making the type `(Int × Int) → Int`.) But, even though `add` is by necessity higher-order in Haskell, you would generally not call …

Comment: … it a "higher-order function", and if you were asked to give an example of a higher-order function, you would probably answer `map` or `flip` but not `add`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

*Unary* is another way of saying "of [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) one". A one parameter function is said to be unary, whereas a two parameters function is binary, three is ternary and so forth...

The same principle applies to types. `List[A]` or `Set[A]`, for example, takes one type `A` to form a new proper type, whereas `Map[A, B]` takes two and is said to be a binary type constructor.

On a side note, types which abstract over a type constructor are called higher kinded types (e.g : `Monad[F[_]]`)