# generic type parameters in nested generic type

Tags: java, scala, collections, interface

I have written this interface as part of a framework.

```
public interface CollectionFactory {

    public <T> Collection<T> newCollection();
}
```

But I want the implementer to be able to define the returned type of the collection so they won’t have to cast like:

```
public interface CollectionFactory<C extends Collection> {
    public C newCollection();
}
```

The problem is that I then lose typesafety on T. I would like it to be

```
public interface CollectionFactory<C extends Collection> {
     public <T> C<T> newCollection();
}
```

And I don’t want to specify T in advance like so:

```
public interface CollectionFactory<T, C extends Collection<T>> {
    public C newCollection();
}
```

To the best of my knowledge this is not possible. 
**Would someone like to surprise me?**

Also, just as an appetizer, does anyone know if something similar to this is possible in say… ***Scala***?

Comment: What error are you getting with that last one?

Comment: Can you share some of the context with us? Maybe you don't need C at all and simple inheritance will cut it.

Comment: @durron597 - Not getting an error, it’s just missing the use case. I don’t want to do it that way :) it binds my CollectionFactory instance to a specific T type at initialization, and that means a different factory per type, which is missing the point.

Comment: @AdamArold It’s more of a theoretical exercise, it’s just a bit of old code I remembered and wanted to make typesafe when I came upon this issue. Every now and then I encounter problems with java’s generic model and I wonder if it’s only me…

Comment: Maybe you ain't using the right tool for the task. Java generics is not a swiss army knife.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala, you can use [higher-kinded types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala) if you want to parametrize over both `C` and `T` in this way:

```
// means that C has a single type parameter and C[T] extends Seq[T] whatever T is
// or C[_] <: Seq[_] which means C[T] must extend Seq[Something] but not necessarily Seq[T]
trait SeqFactory[C[T] <: Seq[T]] { 
  def newSeq[T]: C[T]
}
```

Example implementation:

```
object ListFactory extends SeqFactory[List] { 
  def newSeq[T] = List() 
}
```

You are correct that this can't be done in Java, but depending on the purpose, @Dylan's or @CostiCiudatu's solution may be good enough even if they are less typesafe.

Comment: I will learn to read that scala piece more in depth. Thanks.
I will keep the question open so that java buffs can still give ideas though, if you don’t mind.

Answer (score 3):

On a per-method-invocation basis, you can try something like:

```
public interface CollectionFactory {
    public <T, C extends Collection<T>> C newCollection();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it’s a good try - but it is missing the use case.
For the CollectionFactory to be typesafe, C must be determined on the CollectionFactory interface. 
consider a HashSetCollectionFactory and an ArrayListCollectionFactory that will each return their respective types.
Your solution will allow ArrayListCollectionFactory to potentially return a HashSet.

Comment: Actually I got the point; but I'm afraid that's as close as you can get to it in Java. Anyway, a more detailed description of the usecase may help if you are also interested in alternative approaches for reaching this goal.