# Difficulty writing method with partially applied type parameter and typetag

Tags: scala, type-parameter, partially-applied-type

I am looking for a way to remove type parameter `S` from the call to `apply` in the following example:

```
object Attribute {
  trait Int    [S] extends Attribute[S]
  trait Boolean[S] extends Attribute[S]  // etc.
}
sealed trait Attribute[S]

trait Attributes[S] {
  protected def get(key: String): Option[Attribute[S]]

  def apply[A <: Attribute[S]](key: String)
                              (implicit tag: reflect.ClassTag[A]): Option[A] = 
    get(key) match {
      case Some(attr: A) => Some(attr)
      case _             => None
    }
}
```

With the above definition, a test case would be:

```
trait Test[S] {
  def map: Attributes[S]

  map[Attribute.Int[S]]("foo")
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is **modify the `apply` definition** to allow the following:

```
trait Test2[S] {
  def map: Attributes[S]

  map[Attribute.Int]("foo")   // use partially applied attribute type
}
```

---

**EDIT**: So following up on the suggestion of Marius and the comments, why is the following still producing an erasure warning:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

trait Attributes[S] {
  protected def get(key: String): Option[Attribute[S]]

  def apply[A[x] <: Attribute[x]](key: String)
                                 (implicit tag: TypeTag[A[S]]): Option[A[S]] =
    get(key) match {
      case Some(attr: A[S]) => Some(attr)
      case _                => None
    }
}
```

To me that clearly doesn't make sense. On the one hand I have the full type tag for `A[S]` available. On the other hand, it should even work completely in its absence, as `Attribute` is invariant in `S`, so if I get an `Option[Attribute[S]]`, and I match against `Some(attr: A[x])`, the only possibility is that `x == S`.

---

**EDIT 2**: The condition for the solution is that the shape of `Attribute` trait is not changed, e.g. not moving type constructor parameter `S` to a member field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered leveraging the `unapply` of the implicit `ClassTag`?  If I understand the docs correctly, the `unapply` from the tag will return a None if `attr` does not fully match its type.  If it does match, it will return a Some of type `A[S]`.  So refactored to use unapply, your code would look like this:

```
def apply[A[_] <: Attribute[_]](key: String)
  (implicit tag: reflect.ClassTag[A[S]]): Option[A[S]] =
  get(key) match {
    case Some(attr) => tag.unapply(attr)
    case _             => None
  }
```

Comment: Excellent! I have never seen that before. I will add an answer that shows your method in the context.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want higher-kinded types. I rewrote your code like so:

```
trait Attributes[S] {
  protected def get(key: String): Option[Attribute[S]]

  def apply[A[_] <: Attribute[_]](key: String)
                              (implicit tag: reflect.ClassTag[A[S]]): Option[A[S]] =
    get(key) match {
      case Some(attr: A[S]) => Some(attr)
      case _             => None
    }
}
```

Please note that now the `A` type parameter is a higher order type. As such, at each occurrence within the `apply` method you will need to "apply" `A` to another type in order to obtain a proper type.

This question provides more insight for higher-order types:

[What is a higher kinded type in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala)

Comment: The problem with this version is, the ClassTag **does not kick in here**: `warning: abstract type pattern A[S] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`.

Comment: Yes, that is strange. If I add a `println(tag)` within the `apply` method it prints the correct type name, so I don't know what's wrong. Maybe it should be elevated to its own SO question.

Comment: Use a `TypeTag`. `ClassTags` only capture the erased type.

Comment: @gzm0 yes I tried that. The warning about the erasure doesn't go, though.

Answer (score 1):

One way.  Note that it takes a certain chutzpah to call any type an Int, even a nested one.

```
import scala.reflect._

sealed trait Attribute {
  type S
}

object Attribute {
  trait Ints extends Attribute { type S = Int }
}

/** A container for attributes of a certain type.
 */
trait Attributes[E] {
  type Attr = Attribute { type S <: E }
  protected def get(key: String): Option[Attr]

  /** Retrieve the value for the given key.
   *  @tparam A must be our notion of Attribute
   *  @return optionally the A you asked for
   */
  def apply[A <: Attr](key: String)(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]): Option[A] =
    get(key) match {
      case Some(attr: A) => Some(attr)
      case _             => None
    }
}
trait Test2 {
  /** Map keys to ints. */
  def map: Attributes[Int]

  /** Retrieve a value. */
  map[Attribute.Ints]("foo")   // use partially applied attribute type
}
```

Comment: Moving the `S` type parameter of `Attribute` to a type member is not an option in my case, I'm afraid. (Regarding `Int` - well, it's an attribute carrying an expression evaluating to `Int`, so any other name would be confusing)

Answer (score 0):

This is just to show that @cmbaxter 's answer works as expected. I'll restate the initial code as well, so that it is fully executable:

// **Attribute Interface**

```
object Attribute {
  trait Int    [S] extends Attribute[S]
  trait Boolean[S] extends Attribute[S]  // etc.
}
sealed trait Attribute[S]
```

// **Attribute Map Interface**

```
trait Attributes[S] {
  protected def get(key: String): Option[Attribute[S]]

  def apply[A[_] <: Attribute[_]](key: String)
    (implicit tag: reflect.ClassTag[A[S]]): Option[A[S]] =
    get(key) match {
      case Some(attr) => tag.unapply(attr)
      case _          => None
    }  
  }
}
```

// **Test Case**

```
class Test {
  val map = new Attributes[Foo] {
    def get(key: String) = key match {
      case "foo" => Some(new Attribute.Int    [Foo] { override def toString = "I" })
      case "bar" => Some(new Attribute.Boolean[Foo] { override def toString = "B" })
      case _     => None
    }
  }

  println(s"An int attr named `foo`: ${map[Attribute.Int    ]("foo")}")
  println(s"A bool attr named `foo`: ${map[Attribute.Boolean]("foo")}")
  println(s"An int attr named `bar`: ${map[Attribute.Int    ]("bar")}")
  println(s"A bool attr named `bar`: ${map[Attribute.Boolean]("bar")}")
  println(s"An int attr named `???`: ${map[Attribute.Int    ]("???")}")
  println(s"A bool attr named `???`: ${map[Attribute.Boolean]("???")}")
}
```

// **Running**

```
new Test

An int attr named `foo`: Some(I)
A bool attr named `foo`: None
An int attr named `bar`: None
A bool attr named `bar`: Some(B)
An int attr named `???`: None
A bool attr named `???`: None
```