# Scala type parameter vs. type field when extending higher kinded type

Tags: scala, inheritance, types

I thought of type fields as a more powerful syntax for type parameters, but a come across an example in which I can express my intent via the latter but not the former.
The thing is that trait `A` compiles, while trait `B` does not.

```
trait Box[T]

trait A[T] extends (Box[T] => Box[T]) {
    override def apply(box: Box[T]): Box[T] = identity(box)
}

trait B extends (Box[T] => Box[T]) {
    type T
    override def apply(box: Box[T]): Box[T] = identity(box)
}
```

Is there a way to express what is expressed in `A` using type field as in `B`?

EDIT:
Error message:

```
not found: type T
trait B extends (Box[T] => Box[T]) {
not found: type T
trait B extends (Box[T] => Box[T]) {
```

Comment: can you add the error message from B?

Answer (score 1):

The `override` is useless in the current code, re-add if necessary.

Using an `abstract type member` will create concrete type to pass as a parameter with the placeholder syntax.

```
trait Box[T]

trait A[T] extends (Box[T] => Box[T]) {
    def apply(box: Box[T]): Box[T] = identity(box)
}
```

For `B`, using the `type` member T with `Box[T] => Box[T]` will:

- force extending classes to adhere to the type bound.
- create a concrete type to pass as a parameter

  `trait B extends (Box[_] => Box[_]) {
      type T <: (Box[T] => Box[T])
      def apply(box: Box[T]): Box[T] = identity(box)
  }`

The compiler is telling you it can't find a `type T` to pass to the `type constructor`.
In the case of `B`, you are trying to pass it before defining it.

The `higherKind` placeholder syntax will pass the inner `type T` to the `type constructor`.

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala) will be a good read.