# For "trait Queue[T]", is `Queue` a type?

Tags: scala, types, traits

Defined a trait in scala:

```
trait Queue[T]
```

Is `Queue` a type? Or something else, e.g. a type constructor?

From http://artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html#19.3 of book "programming in scala", it says:

> Queue, as defined in Listing 19.4, is a trait, but not a type.

But someone thinks it is a type, so I totally confused.

Is it a type or not? If not, what it is exactly?

Comment: "higher-kinded type" is a name for things like `Queue`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala

Comment: You can call it `type constructor` as well.

Answer (score 4):

The following sentence answers your question:

> Queue, as defined in Listing 19.4, is a trait, but not a type. ***Queue is not a type because it takes a type parameter.***

We call `Queue` a **generic type**. You cannot use it alone, otherwise the compiler will complain

> trait Queue takes type parameters

Try this:

```
type Q1 = Queue[Int]
//type Qwrong = Queue
```

Comment: Not quite correct. You can use `Queue` without type parameter in any place that expects a higher kinded type.