# Implicit String conversion in scala doesnt compile

Tags: scala, implicit

I've attempted to implement an implicit string conversion, as an experiment with creating scala object "factories", for example, in this case, I'd like to create an employee object from a string.

```
implicit def s2act(name: String) = new Actor[Employee](){
  override def toString() : String = {
    name
  }
};
//two failed attempts at leveraging the implicit conversion below...
processActor("jim")
def boss : Actor = new String("Jim");
```

However, the above implicit binding fails to be identified by the compiler.  Why does the compiler fail to process this implicit binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the error you should get from your code is that "class Actor takes type parameters".

a more correct code will be :

```
def boss : Actor[Employee] = new String("Jim");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's the signature of `processActor`, but judging from the signature of `boss` I think the problem is you don't provide type parameter to `Actor`.

`Actor` itself is a type constructor, which means that it takes a type to construct a new type.

`Actor` is not a type, and you cannot use it in your function/method signature, but `Actor[Employee]` is a type.

Change your `boss` to this

`def boss: Actor[Employee] = new String("Jim")`

Related post: [What is a higher kinded type in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala)