# Can I mimic Scala SIP-18-syle imports?

Tags: scala

Scala [SIP 18](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nlkvpoIRkx7at1qJEZafJwthZ3GeIklTFhqmXMvTX9Q/edit) provides a way to force users to provide an import statement to use certain advanced or unsafe language features. For instance, in order to use [higher kinded types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6427289/2186890), you need to

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
```

or you will get a compiler warning telling you you are using an advanced feature.

Is there any way that I can reproduce or mimic this behavior in my own library? For example I may have:

```
trait MongoRepository[E <: Entity] {
  val casbahCollection: com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection
}
```

I have made the `casbahCollection` public to expose the underlying collection to the user *in case they need it*. But it's really not something I want my users to do because it's a leaky abstraction. So I want to force them to do something like this:

```
import my.library.mongo.leakyAbstraction
```

Before doing something like this:

```
widgetRepo.casbahCollection.find()
```

Is it possible? Is there some way I might provide a similar behavior that's a little more effective than just placing a big ugly warning in the docs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could fake it with an implicit, similar to the way `Await.result` works in `scala.concurrent`.

First create a `sealed trait` that represents a "permit" to directly access your DAO:

```
@implicitNotFound("Import my.library.mongo.leakyAbstraction to directly access Mongo")
sealed trait CanAccessMongo
```

And then an object that extends it:

```
implicit object leakyAbstraction extends CanAccessMongo
```

These must be in the same file.  By making `CanAccessMongo` sealed, code outside the same file will not be able to extend it.

Then in `MongoRepository` make `cashbahCollection` a function (change `val` to `def`).  You'll probably want a private val that actually creates it, but we need the function to limit access.

```
def cashbahCollection(implicit permit: CanAccessMongo) = ...
```

Now users of your library will have to bring `leakyAbstraction` into scope in order to call that function.  If they don't, they'll get the error message specified in `implicitNotFound`.

The obvious downside is that all your library code will have to have `leakyAbstraction` in scope as well.

Comment: Thanks that's great! I had just had a similar idea using an implicit conversion but yours in much more elegant.

Comment: In regards to library code needing `leakyAbstraction` in scope, I can do make `MongoRepo` have a `private[library] coll: com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection` and `def cashbahCollection(implicit permit: CanAccessMongo) = coll`. So within the library I just access `coll`.