# What's the relation between "generics" and "higher-order types"?

Tags: java, scala, generics, higher-order-types

From this question: [What is a higher kinded type in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala), I understand what is `higher-order types`(also `first-order type` and `proper type`).

But there is still a question: What's the relation between `generics` and "higher-order types"?

I know Java supports `generics`, which is like the `first-order` type in Scala.

Which of the following are correct?

1. In Scala, only the `first-order type` is `generics`
2. In Scala, `first-order` and `higher-order` types are both belong to `generics`
3. In Java, the `generics` just mean `first-order` type, it's not complete
4. `generics` is a common term means we can "abstract" on types, no matter `first-order` or `higher-order`

Answer (score 1):

I'd say (1.) is wrong.
I'm not sure about (3.) because I'm a bit out of practice concerning Java. 
But I'd say (4.) is pretty accurate and somewhat similar to (2.).

As far as I know, the term *generics* refers just to the usage of type parameters. It applies to both *first-order* and *higher-order* types or functions.

Offtopic (and somewhat nerdish): Does anyone else see a hidden reference to *Wing Commander* in (2.)