# type inference fails in a generic scala function

Tags: scala, collections, type-inference

consider a simple function that operates on collections `distinctBy`, which, like `distinct` remove "duplicates" (which are not necessary actual duplicates):

```
import scala.collection.TraversableLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.mutable.{Set=>MSet}

def distinctBy[T,R,Coll]
  (xs: Coll)
  (f: T => R)
  (implicit ev: Coll <:< TraversableLike[T,Coll], 
   cbf: CanBuildFrom[Coll,T,Coll]): Coll = {

  val builder = cbf(xs)
  builder.sizeHint(xs.size)
  val seen = MSet.empty[R]

  xs.foreach { elem =>
    if(!seen(f(elem))){
      builder += elem
    }
  }
  builder.result()
}
```

now consider a class to use it on:

```
case class X(i: Int, j: Int)
```

using this function naively fails:

```
scala> distinctBy(Vector(X(1,2),X(3,2),X(1,1),X(2,2)))(_.i)
<console>:14: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.i)
              distinctBy(Vector(X(1,2),X(3,2),X(1,1),X(2,2)))(_.i)
                                                          ^
<console>:14: error: Cannot construct a collection of type scala.collection.immutable.Vector[X] with elements of type Any based on a collection of type scala.collection.immutable.Vector[X].
              distinctBy(Vector(X(1,2),X(3,2),X(1,1),X(2,2)))(_.i)
                                                             ^
```

but if I help the type inferencer, this works:

```
scala> distinctBy(Vector(X(1,2),X(3,2),X(1,1),X(2,2)))((x:X) => x.i)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[X] = Vector(X(1,2), X(3,2), X(1,1), X(2,2))

scala> distinctBy[X,Int,Vector[X]](Vector(X(1,2),X(3,2),X(1,1),X(2,2)))(_.i)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[X] = Vector(X(1,2), X(3,2), X(1,1), X(2,2))
```

to my best understanding, since the function is given in a second argument list, the type inferencer should have picked up that it's a function from `X` to something. and since `X` has a member `i` of type `Int`, all should have been OK with the first try. so, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simplified version works fine for me:

```
object A {
  def f1[T, R](l: List[T])(f: T=>R) = None

  case class X(i: Int, j: Int)

  f1(List(X(1,1),X(2,1)))(_.i)
}
```

As you can see collection in first parameter list has T type that allows scala inference type in second arguments list.

So you need build somehow dependencies between Col and T in your example. Not sure if third implicits parameters list helps here.

UPD.
Looks weird but seems it works:

```
object A {
  def f1[T, R, Col[Z]](l: Col[T])(f: T => R) = None

  case class X(i: Int, j: Int)

  f1(List(X(1,1),X(2,1)))(_.i)
}
```

UPD2.
Rewritten sample from question.

```
  import scala.collection.TraversableLike
  import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  import scala.collection.mutable.{Set=>MSet}

  def distinctBy[T,R,Coll[Z]]
  (xs: Coll[T])
  (f: T => R)
  (implicit ev: Coll[T] <:< TraversableLike[T,Coll[T]],
   cbf: CanBuildFrom[Coll[T],T,Coll[T]]): Coll[T] = {

    val builder = cbf(xs)
    builder.sizeHint(xs.size)
    val seen = MSet.empty[R]

    xs.foreach { elem =>
      if(!seen(f(elem))){
        builder += elem
        seen.add(f(elem))
      }
    }
    builder.result()
  }

  case class X(i: Int, j: Int)

  distinctBy(Vector(X(1,2),X(1,2),X(3,2),X(1,1),X(2,2)))(_.i)
  distinctBy(Map("1" -> X(1,2), "2" -> X(1,2), "3" -> X(3,2)))(_._2.i)
```

Comment: yes' but it would work only on collections that receives exactly one type parameter. i.e. collections like `IntList extends List[Int]`,`Map[K,V]`, cannot be used with such a function. it won't compile.

Comment: @gilad hoch , i've updated post... that probably not what you've expected .. as T takes different types but not X all the time.

Comment: I can't see how this would work. Could you try implementing `distinctBy` and show how to use it with the failed attempt from my question?

Comment: done. it works as expected with both maps and lists. also I've fixed minor bug in your logic of duplications check.

Comment: yup, this works :) but I still don't understand what you did there. you're not using type `Z` anywhere, so I guess it could have been replaced by `_`, and besides, why is it needed in the first place? I tried testing it with : `class XTraversable extends Traversable[X] {def foreach[U](f: X => U) = {for {i <- 1 to 5; j <- 1 to 5}{f(X(i,j))}}}; distinctBy(new XTraversable)(_.i)` and it worked, so you got it right, I just don't understand it. could you provide an explanation or a refernce I could read to understand it? thanks!

Comment: It's called higher kinded types in Scala.  Please check: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala

Comment: I'm aware of higher kinded types, just don't see how it comes to the help in my case. anyway, thanks :)