# Scala: `m: util.AbstractMap[_, _]` vs `m: util.AbstractMap`?

Tags: scala

What is the difference between `m: util.AbstractMap[_, _]` and `m: util.AbstractMap`?

PS. The question I think holds for any collection, not just this one.

Comment: Just to give you something to google: the first one is an *existential type* and the second one is a *higher-kinded type* or *type constructor*.

Answer (score 1):

In scala you have to necessarily provide the type argument. So in literal sense, you cannot do `new util.AbstractMap`.

Well if you think of it, its correct. In Java, one can avoid giving the parametric type and the code compiles, so as to be backward compatible with pre-java5 code. But in scala, generics have been a part from the start.

If the question was for instead something like this:

```
trait MonoidK[F[_]]{...}
MonoidK[List].combine[Int](List(1,2,3),List(4))
```

Where we do not provide the argument types for `List`, then `List` in this case is a Type Constructor to which arguments have to be provided later (in `combine` method). `MonoidK` in this case is supporsedly called higher kinded type. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala) is a good read on this topic for more details.