# Why Is Functor a Higher-Kinded type

Tags: scala, category-theory

I have following functor definition

```
trait Functor[F[_]] { 
    def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}
object ListFunctor extends Functor[List] { //
    def map[A, B](f: A => B)(data: List[A]): List[B] = data map f
}
```

In scala, it is very common that `F` is a collection type, such as List,Seq,Option, I would ask why Functor has to be higher kinded type, and what does the type parameter `F` really mean?

Comment: Functor is a common interface for many (higher kinded) types like List and Option. The type parameter F says "this is the type we define our interface for".

Comment: Thanks @n.m. Your explanation makes sense from the code's view. I want to ask why functor takes form such as `Functor[F[_]]`. It looks to me that functor is aiming to transform F[A] to F[B] given A=>B, F's meaning here doesn't really matter. It can be a container or context or some others, as long as F[A] and F[B] is meaningful.

Comment: If it weren't higher kinded than what would the signature of `map` look like?

Comment: `Functor[F[_]]` looks like that because we want to use `Functor[List]` and `Functor[Option]` and `Functor[Stream]` and others like that. `List`, `Option` and `Stream` are all higher-kinded types that have exactly one type parameter. `F[_]` is a way to express this last fact. `_` is a placeholder for the type parameter of `F`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why Functor has to be higher kinded type

`Functor` has to be higher kinded because we want to *abstract over a type parameter* which itself takes a type parameter (we call this a *type constructor*, think `Functor[List]` as a concrete example).

The type of types that `Functor` deals with are called "first order kinds", their kind is of `* -> *`. When you looking at concrete instances for `Functor`, you see we dont provide the inner type parameter. For example, when you define a functor for `List` as you did in your example, you define it as a `Functor[List]`. We're not creating a functor for a proper type (i.e. `List[Int]`), but rather any type contained inside the `List`. This abstraction brings great power, because you can utilize it for any proper `List` type (of kind *), be it `List[String]`, `List[Int]`, etc..

I always like to refer to the image drawn by Adriaan Moore in his paper "Genrics Of A Higher Kind":

[image: Higher Kinds]

> What does the type parameter F really mean

`F`s sole purpose is to define a contract with the implementer of the `Functor`. By the signature of `F` we can deduce what kind of type `Functor` expects. When we see that it has one "placeholder" (`[_]`) we know, by convention, that this means that `F` should take a single type parameter. If we think about all the types that take a single type parameter, we can see that there are many, for example `List`, `Option`, `Try`, `Future`, `Task`, etc.

For a more broad explanation regarding higher kinded types, see [What is a higher kinded type in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala)

Comment: tl;dr: By definition. :) Of course, if Higher-Kinded Type is already defined.

Answer (score 1):

I'd answer this a bit differently. The presence of a (higher-kinded) type parameter `F[_]` in `Functor` signature means `Functor` is a typeclass. Typeclasses is a Scala feature that allows one to add features to existing types without modifying them. So `Functor[F[_]]` here is not a single type, but a blueprint for many other types. Or, in other words, it is not a single type, but a class of types, hence the word "typeclass".

Now to create a concrete functor, e.g. functor of list, one needs to pass that concrete type as a type parameter to that blueprint, and that concrete type itself has to have one type parameter, by mathematical definition of functor, if you wish. This is what higher-kinded type `F[_]` in `Functor` signature means.

Comment: Hey downvoters, care to explain the reason for your vote?