# What is the type of scala.concurrent.Future?

Tags: scala

I try to understand what's the data type of scala.concurrent.Future?

I found the following types from the scala lang documentation, but still unsure the differences between them, and when to use which one?

```
trait Future[+T] extends Awaitable[T] //for concurrent programming
object Future extends AnyRef //not sure?

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/concurrent/Future$.html
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but I got an impression that you need first to get some scala basis, what is trait, what is companion object, and other stuff.

Back to your question.
When you want to execute something concurrently, you can wrap it in `Future`. Your code has some output type (`SomeType`, could be `Unit` - equivalent of `void`), after wrapping into `Future` you will get `Future[SomeType]` - it is extension of trait `Future[+T]`. Than you need some execution context (thread pool) to execute your `Future`.

Try to find and read "Programming in Scala" written by Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon and Bill Venners, very good for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Like a collection (`List`, `Array`, etc.), a `Future` is a type that works on/with another type. A useful comparison is the `Option` type.

Just as an `Option[Int]` *might* be an `Int` value (and it might not), a `Future[Int]` might not be an `Int` value *yet*. It could be that the `Int` value is still being calculated, or being extracted from a database table, or being retrieved from a distant network location. Whatever the cause, if it's a slow process there's no reason to wait for it. Turn it into a `Future[Int]` so that your program can go on with other important tasks.

As for the `object Future`, that is a singleton object that has a handful of methods for handling/manipulating existing `Future` elements. `Future.sequence()` is a useful example.

Comment: Future is not higher-kinded. Neither is Option. They're just generic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you are talking about the *trait* `Future` or the singleton object `Future`. I will answer both.

The trait doesn't have a type. It *is* a type.

All singleton objects `foo` have the singleton type `foo.type`, so the singleton object `Future` has the singleton type `Future.type`.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, `object` is a singleton class, which means, that there only exists a single instance during the runtime of the application. There are several ways to implement singletons in most languages, but most often, you risk some issues such as thread safety. Scala's `object` takes care of the implementation of this pattern for you.

A common pattern in Scala is creating an `object` that has the same name as a `class`, like the one in your example. This is called a companion object. A common use for these is for essentially defining the equivalents of `static` methods from Java. You can declare methods that are common for all instances, or methods that handle and manipulate instances of the `class`. In Java, for example, you would declare them as `static` in the body of the `class` itself. The companion object helps you with separation of concern in this case.