# Difference between F[_] and F[T] In Scala when used in type constructors

Tags: scala, types, type-constructor

This question is about _ as used in type constructor and not when used in defining existential types.

So the question is what is the difference when `_` is used as type parameter instead of a variable like `T`. For example difference between `F[_]` and `F[T]`.

The only difference I can think of is that with `F[_]` the parameter itself can have as many holes as possible...that is `F[_]` can become `F[Int]` or `F[Future[Option[Int]]]` etc...while when you have `F[T]` the `T` can only be a proper type...that is `F[String]` or `F[Int]` etc.

Is this a correct assumption? and is that the main difference between `F[_]` and `F[T]`? or there are more?

What about the case where the two are used as type parameters? For example, what is the difference between `trait Functor [F[_]]` and `trait Functor [F[T]]`?

Is there any semantic difference if the functor trait is defined as `trait Functor [F[_]]` instead of `trait Functor [F[T]]`?

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco no, that did not help. That was more concerned with providing clarification around the meaning of higher-order types. It was not about clarifying the difference between use of _ or variable in a type class parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote [the specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#type-parameters):

> > The above scoping restrictions are generalized to the case of nested type parameter clauses, which declare higher-order type parameters. Higher-order type parameters (the type parameters of a type parameter `t`) are only visible in their immediately surrounding parameter clause (possibly including clauses at a deeper nesting level) and in the bounds of t. Therefore, their names must only be pairwise different from the names of other visible parameters. Since the names of higher-order type parameters are thus often irrelevant, they may be denoted with a `_`, which is nowhere visible.
> >
> > Example
> >
> > Here are some well-formed type parameter clauses:
> >
> > ```
> > [S, T]
> > [@specialized T, U]
> > [Ex <: Throwable]
> > [A <: Comparable[B], B <: A]
> > [A, B >: A, C >: A <: B]
> > [M[X], N[X]]
> > [M[_], N[_]] // equivalent to previous clause
> > [M[X <: Bound[X]], Bound[_]]
> > [M[+X] <: Iterable[X]]
> > ```

So if you have no bounds, as in `Functor [F[T]]`, there's no difference at all from `Functor [F[_]]`.

Comment: The plot thickens! I actually wasn't expecting that there will be no semantic difference between `Functor [F[T]]` and `Functor [F[_]]`! This is largely due to the fact that the `F[_]` flavour get used most of the time when defining things like Functor, Monad etc, while `F[T]` get used for defining types that are more similar to Java generics!

Comment: In "types that are more similar to Java generics" you are going to use the parameter name somewhere in the definition; in `HigherKind[F[T]]`, you are going to use `F` in the definition, but not `T`.

Comment: @dade I'm surprised that `trait Functor[F[T]]` even compiles! But I can totally see why people don't use this notation: it gives the false impression that there are two type parameters `F` and `T`, but in reality, there's only one, `F`. Your question is proof of the confusion it causes. From this perspective, `trait Functor[F[_]]` makes much more sense and should be regarded as the One True Way.

Answer (score 3):

> The only difference I can think of is that with `F[_]` the parameter
>   itself can have as many holes as possible...that is `F[_]` can become
>   `F[Int]` or `F[Future[Option[Int]]]` etc...while when you have `F[T]`
>   the `T` can only be a proper type...that is `F[String]` or `F[Int]`
>   etc.
>
> Is this a correct assumption?

Note that `Future[Option[Int]]` is a *proper* type of the same kind as `Int` or `String`. We can convince ourself by using `:kind` command in Scala REPL

```
scala> :kind -v Future[Option[Int]]
scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]]'s kind is A
*
This is a proper type.

scala> :kind -v Int
Int's kind is A
*
This is a proper type.
```

To drive the point, consider the following complicated-looking type

```
Function3[Int, Tuple2[Double, List[Int]], Char, Future[Either[String, Int]]]
```

It is still just a simple concrete `*` type

```
scala> :kind -v Function3[Int, Tuple2[Double, List[Int]], Char, Future[Either[String, Int]]]
(Int, (Double, List[Int]), Char) => scala.concurrent.Future[Either[String,Int]]'s kind is A
*
This is a proper type.
```

Hence we see the shape of `Future[Option[Int]]` is simply `*`, and `F[_]` does not need any extra "holes" to fit it. Both `F[_]` and `F[T]` type constructors take a type argument of exactly same shape, namely `*`, no more, nor less. For example, let us try to fit in more than it can handle

```
trait Bar[F[_]]   // Bar is type constructor of higher order kind  - shape (* -> *) -> *
def g[F[_]] = println("g takes type constructor type argument of * -> * shape")

scala> g[Bar]
        ^
       error: kinds of the type arguments (Bar) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type F).
       Bar's type parameters do not match type F's expected parameters:
       type F has 1 type parameter, but type _ has 0
```

This errors because actual `(* -> *) -> *` shape of `Bar` does not fit expected `* -> *` shape of `F`.