# Type constructor parameter inference

Tags: scala, types, scala-cats, category-theory, type-constructor

I'm going through "Scala with cats". In 3.5.2 (p. 58, bottom) there is an example:

```
def doMath[F[_]](start: F[Int])(implicit functor: Functor[F]): F[Int] =
    start.map(n => n + 1 * 2)
```

And the usage is pretty straightforward:

```
import cats.instances.option._ // for Functor
import cats.instances.list._
// for Functor
doMath(Option(20))
// res3: Option[Int] = Some(22)
doMath(List(1, 2, 3))
// res4: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)
```

How should I understand the type constructor in the method signature (`F[_]`)? A couple of pages earlier it was said, that the type parameter should be provided to create a type. Here the whole thing (`F[_]`) is a type parameter and it looks, that `_` is a wildcard, so that the compiler can infer the type parameter of `F`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type constructor `F[_]` is required to be a member of the `Functor` typeclass. This constraint is put on `F` by the implicit parameter list

```
(implicit functor: Functor[F])
```

The whole signature

```
def doMath[F[_]](start: F[Int])(implicit functor: Functor[F]): F[Int]
```

might be interpreted as follows

> Given any type constructor `F` that is a member of `Functor`
> typeclass, then `doMath` can transform effectful value of type `F[Int]` to
> another effectful value of type `F[Int]`.

where I use the phrase *effectful value* to emphasise that it is not a value of raw type such as `Int` but instead a value of type constructed after applying type constructor `F` to type argument `Int`, namely `F[Int]`.

Furthermore I use the phrase *member of* in the [sense of](https://gitter.im/scala/scala?at=5a80395d93be87284da24a45)

> forms a, or participates in, or has a relationship

Note the usage of underscore `_` in this context is not related to inference. The `F[X]` and `F[_]` type constructor notations mean exactly the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49762658/5205022) thing. The type argument `X` is not used anywhere in the rest of the method signature, and for that reason by convention we use the underscore syntax `F[_]`. Another convention is to use lower-case `x` in `F[x]`, as opposed to `F[X]`, to emphasise `x` is not used.

Indeed `F[_]` is a type parameter in its own right and when type constructor `Functor` is applied to it we get *proper* type `Functor[F]` even though both `F` and `Functor` are type constructors, for example

```
scala> :kind -v List
List's kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.

scala> :kind -v cats.Functor
cats.Functor's kind is X[F[A]]
(* -> *) -> *
This is a type constructor that takes type constructor(s): a higher-kinded type.

scala> :kind -v cats.Functor[List]
cats.Functor[List]'s kind is A
*
This is a proper type.
```

Comment: Minor note, it is best to say that the type constructor `F` should hold the functor laws. Or that it exists an instance of functor for the type constructor `F`. Rather than say that `F` is a member of functor. Remember that the main conceptual difference between subtyping and typeclasses is that in the former **A** _is a_ **B**, whereas in the last **A** _has a_ (instance of) **B**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I use the word _member_ in the sense of https://danielwestheide.com/blog/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes/#type-classes-to-the-rescue which I guess comes from Haskell, however I do see how this can be confusing in light of OO terminology.

Comment: Uhm, first time I see the expression member to be used in the context of typeclasses. Maybe, as you say, it is from Haskell? Interesting article, thanks for sharing.