# TypeScript - get type of generic class parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I need to implement a type `GetClassParameter<T>` that would work like this:

```
class Foo<T> {

}

type foo = Foo<string>

type x = GetClassParameter<foo>; // should be string
```

I'm sorry if it's a duplicate, I couldn't find it. I only found a hardcoded solution ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62733441/4925661)):

```
type GetFooParameter<T extends Foo<any>> = T extends Foo<infer R> ? R : unknown;
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
    public value: T;
    public value2: string;
    constructor (value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

type BaseT<T> = {
  value: T  // if removed, it wouldn't work
}
type GetClassParameter<T extends BaseT<any>> = T extends BaseT<infer R> ? R : unknown;

type x = GetClassParameter<foo> // string - almost works, requires shared property with a T
```

The above almost works but requires BaseT to have a `value: T` property.

Is there a way to do it without hardcoding anything, assuming the target class has only one generic parameter?

### Update:

Another take, unsuccessful.

```
type ClassLike<T> = (new <T>(...args: any[]) => any);
type GetClassParameter<T extends ClassLike<any>> = T extends ClassLike<infer R> ? R : unknown;
type x = GetClassParameter<foo> // error, does not satisfy constraint
```

### Update 2

It's not possible currently. Nevertheless, I tried a hack to define BaseT with value property and then removed it. It doesn't work. I'm adding it as a reference if someone had a similar idea to save you time. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgIwAwB4BQVNQPJQgD2AgDsATAZynOACcBLYgcwBoMsARPQkiq2hlmgB8UALxQA3gG0A0lAY4AugC4oACgBKEAMYB7GqRTtmUYhABuEGiIBkULXoMpq9JiZlCAlLMUBfNGigkLCI6Fg4XERklC4CrOGcBFG8sW5smAD0GfLk5HDQAIwAbEgFABzpUABiurqRPJTwyCjYJuwi4k2orVDtwmLVtVLYigFZUAAWwMBg5MpZ1ACG2gDWupY0AGYANroA7gB0egC2GQCO%20dR0usTkGQAsBfcA7CVFAMwZQRDk2vRgwAAtDQIMd1hBASsICBAZsaLpjoDvoC8ghaMtgNdiEjwBBAricMc6MAwlhWpVEtxonxXIJwuM6Ll8lBiqUKuEanUkg0Qs0oSBdJscG0OrzUPzBcLekJ%20uIAAp0VYtEycqQSoUjGX44IAIUW5AgABUAOrEiYANUW23yKENookbHMVvyqkNaH8aHGexuAHJgFBvTQVlAEDpFnADfJgD7KCDSHBtBBSFBgHVjlZoBIoL4DrAERBgBMBFBjhH-RHoIaoIsyCmJhmY6Y6ntFiBq-C4LXidroHqDYbbaLsESSX2jabC5brRBByYfU7pz6hABuKABbTbfWUTmDySVPS3WgJ1M0dQLl1QQ2ePfhfwe75QADiBYAwpvcnLFjRFumiDRbfU1JjgONYgEIopVtyQH6kaKAMJsVj2CIAD89hQKonYrMQ%20zEMuAQPpstQDDuqSMCu%20EEvgAzPsAb5bp%2036-lYKCEboIjjJh2F7MQARAA)

### Update 3

I'm adding a workaround I'm using to get the class parameter type for 2  classes that have nothing in common (it can be extended to cover more classes just by adding additional conditional).

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECCIAcAWYA8AVAfNA3gKGkOgQCcBLANzABcBTaMALmnQG48BfPPUSGAIVrU0WXASKlKNegCNmbTt2oBPBPQDiQgMLgoABTAkwAWyG0SAMQD2JeMjCDhGaLQAedAHYATGHZSowD2VsAB9oRzRA4OwAXnFCdBd3Wm9fRH8yDwAzc2gAJUx46AB%20fOh5JM8fcKE0TJySfMKiErLmAFcPAGsPKwB3D3Y8FTUGdLBoGLhx1Ahqcg8Ac0KR2VrJmqcPduMZc0Lh1XpXDc1qHT4DI1M6Sxs-B1qA8ewAelfoOYXFw9HlU%200uggVxMZjutnGEVQe2Ebw%202125iAA)

```
class Alpha<T> {
    private a: T;
}

class Beta<T> {
    private b: T;
}

type GetClassParameterForAlphaBeta<T extends Alpha<any> | Beta<any>> =
    T extends Alpha<infer R>
    ? R : T extends Beta<infer R>
    ? R : unknown;

type alpha = Alpha<string>
type beta = Beta<number>

type x = GetClassParameterForAlphaBeta<alpha> // string
type y = GetClassParameterForAlphaBeta<beta> // number
```

Comment: Your updated try can take `GetClassParameter<typeof Foo>`, if that also works for you

Comment: You are right about that. However, passing `GetClassParameter<typeof foo>` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: And the feature that takes the general form of `UtilType<F<T>> => T` is not supported by TS. _Higher kinded type_ is the term, and TS doesn’t have it. So forget perfect solution, best you can get is workarounds with limitations. Your two takes are actually good enough.

Comment: Should be `typeof Foo` uppercase F. `typeof foo` is diff thing.

Comment: Well, I cannot use `typeof Foo` because I need to get information about the lowercase `foo`, which is `foo = Foo<string>` I couldn't get it from `Foo<T>`. 

Surely if it's not supported, the workaround is good enough, I need this for 2 classes so I could probably use conditional types or something, but it would be nicer of course if if it was flexible.

Comment: I cannot find the issue anymore, but typescript omits the information of generics if they are unused. It is a design limitation.

Comment: I don’t have better answer for your problem, you’ve hit the limit of TS. FYI I wrote an answer about [higher kinded type in TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55683711/replace-generic-interface-type-parameter) years ago. Only remotely related to your problem. If you wanna dig deeper you can take a look.

Comment: I updated my question to add the workaround with conditionals to get the type for 2 or more different classes.

Answer (score 4):

Cannot be done yet - purely as a type. There is an open issue that aims to allow passing higher-kind generic types through: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213

Its an issue that is a bane to many trying to type highly moddable js-libs
(like levelup).

Just to give you a much easier example of something that doesn't work:

```
interface Dummy<T> {};

declare function getParam<P, T extends Dummy<P>>(a: T): P;

let a = getParam(null as Dummy<string>);
```

here a is `unknown`

the only real work around is to move the generic parameter into the dummy interface as a fake property - but then everything passed to this will need that fake property defined too - or you're back to `unknown`

```
interface Dummy<T> {
  a?: T
};

declare function getParam<P, T extends Dummy<P>>(a: T): T["a"]

let a = getParam(null as Foo<string>);
```

a is now `string` but typescript still has no idea what `P` is

Comment: Not related but it is possible to do in Flow