# How to read types within square brackets in Scala?

Tags: scala, akka

I am relatively new to the Scala language, and I came across code that looks like this (while reviewing Akka).

```
val someFlow: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] = Flow[Int].reduce[Int](_ + _)
```

How can I read type annotations like: `Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a higher kinded type in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala)

Comment: @ShankarShastri I'm not sure this has to do with higher kinded types

Comment: Its similar to when you read a `List[Int]` or `Map[String, String]`. Things like lists, maps are genralized over the type parameter which enables you to just define a `List[A]` once and then use that to construct a `List[Int]`, `List[String]` etc by filling in that type parameter `A`. In a sense you can think of `List` as a type constructor  (called as `kinds` in Scala) which gives you the types `List[Int]`, `List[String]` etc when you provide the type argument. Then come the `higer kinded type` which take a `kind` as parameter such as `Functor[F[_]]`, `Monad[F[_]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a value-level function application

```
((x: Int) => List(x))(42)
```

where value-lambda `(x: Int) => List(x)` is applied to value argument `42`.

Consider a *type*-level function application

```
([X] =>> List[X])[Int]
```

where type-lambda `[X] =>> List[X]` is applied to *type* argument `Int`.

Now [compare](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/lvx3SMKUTMKj4foU6xKGMA) the two in

```
scala> val v: ([X] =>> List[X])[Int] = ((x: Int) => List(x))(42)
val v: List[Int] = List(42)
```

We see that a type lambda or *type constructor* constructs a *proper* type `List[Int]` which accommodates a value `List(42)` constructed by a value lambda or value constructor.

Note the similarity between `=>` and `=>>`. Now `=>>` syntax is only available in Dotty (Scala 3) which brings [type lambdas](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/type-lambdas.html), however I believe it is already a helpful device to grok what types such as `Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed]` really are

```
([In, Out, Mat] =>> Flow[In, Out, Mat])[Int, Int, NotUsed]
```

These are the facilities to support the techniques of *polymorphism* which allows us to think in ever higher levels of abstraction. For example, if `f` takes a box of chocolates

```
def f(v: Box[Chocolate] = ???
```

then `g` takes a box of something `A`

```
def g[A](v: Box[A]) = ???
```

and we can go even higher where `h` takes some kind of container `F` of something `A`

```
def h[F[_], A](v: F[A]) = ???
```

This last form of polymorphism is known as [type constructor polymorphism](https://adriaanm.github.io/research/2010/10/06/new-in-scala-2.8-type-constructor-inference/) and is what separates Scala from many other languages which stop at the box of something.

Comment: In some branches of mathematics, functions are called "value constructors". If you think about them like that, the analogy to type constructors becomes really obvious.