# Scala 2 macro type class derivation for `Coder[P <: Product]` ends with error `P does not take parameters`

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-macros, scala-2.13, defmacro

I am a starter with Scala 2 Macros (before I switch to Dotty) who after trying out the shapeless type class derivation wanted to go one step beyond and write a macro that can generate a type class instances for any `scala.Product` without it.

(for the sake of example let's ignore nested recursive types, so my goal is flat case classes.)

My type class is an abstract class [`Coder[T]`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/Coder.html) (e.g. trait with `encode()` / `decode()`).

So the generated code for:

```scala
case class Pojo(
  s: String,
  i: Int,
  l: List[Int]
)
```

should be something like:

```scala
import com.github.fpopic.scalamacros.Pojo
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder
import java.io.{ByteArrayInputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream}
import java.util

class PojoCoder extends Coder[Pojo] {

  import com.github.fpopic.scalamacros.beam.DefMacroCoder.{
    stringCoder,
    intCoder,
    listCoder
  }

  override def encode(value: Pojo, os: OutputStream): Unit = {
    stringCoder.encode(value.s, os)
    intCoder.encode(value.i, os)
    listCoder(intCoder).encode(value.l, os)
  }

  override def decode(is: InputStream): Pojo = {
    Pojo(
      s = stringCoder.decode(is),
      i = intCoder.decode(is),
      l = listCoder(intCoder).decode(is)
    )
  }

  override def getCoderArguments: util.List[_ <: Coder[_]] = {
    Collections.emptyList()
  }

  override def verifyDeterministic(): Unit =  ()
}
```

(removed fully specified class names to improve readability)

In the macro I try to:

- inspect the `weakTypeOf[P]`
- iterate over each case class constructor field (of type `F`)

  - implicitly find their typeclass `Coder[F]` instance and add it to the tree
  - and append their `encode()` and `decode()` expression to the tree that contributes to the final `Coder[P]` methods.

```scala
def materializeProductCoder[P: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Coder[P]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val tpe = c.weakTypeOf[P]
    val helper = new MacrosHelper[c.type](c)

    val expressions =
      helper.getPrimaryConstructorMembers(tpe).map { field =>
        val fieldTerm = field.asTerm.name // e.g. value.s (for now just s)
        val fieldType = field.typeSignature.finalResultType // e.g. String

        val fieldCoderName = c.freshName(TermName("coder")) // e.g. give friendly name coder$...
        val fieldCoderInstance = // e.g. finds instance of Coder[String]
          c.typecheck(
            tree = q"""_root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[${fieldType}]]""",
            silent = false
          )

        val fieldCoderExpression =
          q"private val ${fieldCoderName}: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[${fieldType}] = ${fieldCoderInstance}"

        val fieldEncodeExpression =
          q"${fieldCoderName}.encode(value.${fieldTerm}, os)" // replace with full relative name (with dots) instead of value

        val fieldDecodeExpression =
          q"${field.asTerm} = ${fieldCoderName}.decode(is)"

        (fieldCoderExpression, fieldEncodeExpression, fieldDecodeExpression)
      }

    val fieldCodersExpression = expressions.map(_._1).distinct
    val coderEncodeExpresions = expressions.map(_._2)
    val coderDecodeExpresions = expressions.map(_._3)

    val coderExpression =
      q"""{
            new org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[${tpe}] {

              {import ${c.prefix}._}

              ..${fieldCodersExpression}

              override def encode(value: ${tpe}, os: java.io.OutputStream): _root_.scala.Unit = {
                ..${coderEncodeExpresions}
              }

              override def decode(is: java.io.InputStream): ${tpe} = {
                ${tpe.typeConstructor}(
                  ..${coderDecodeExpresions}
                )
              }

              override def getCoderArguments: java.util.List[_ <: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[_]] = {
                java.util.Collections.emptyList
              }

              override def verifyDeterministic(): _root_.scala.Unit = ()
            }
          }
      """

    val ret = coderExpression
    c.Expr[Coder[P]](ret)
  }
```

But get an error after invoking `sbt Test / compile`:

(a bit struggling with imports and implicit search so for now having intermediate `private val`s, and distinct is useless)

```scala
{
  final class $anon extends org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[com.github.fpopic.scalamacros.beam.Pojo] {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    {
      import DefMacroCoder._;
      ()
    };
    private val coder$macro$1: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[String] = scala.Predef.implicitly[org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[String]](DefMacroCoder.stringCoder);
    private val coder$macro$2: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[Int] = scala.Predef.implicitly[org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[Int]](DefMacroCoder.intCoder);
    private val coder$macro$3: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[List[Int]] = scala.Predef.implicitly[org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[List[Int]]](DefMacroCoder.listCoder[Int](DefMacroCoder.intCoder));
    override def encode(value: com.github.fpopic.scalamacros.beam.Pojo, os: java.io.OutputStream): _root_.scala.Unit = {
      coder$macro$1.encode(value.s, os);
      coder$macro$2.encode(value.i, os);
      coder$macro$3.encode(value.l, os)
    };
    override def decode(is: java.io.InputStream): com.github.fpopic.scalamacros.beam.Pojo = com.github.fpopic.scalamacros.beam.Pojo(s = coder$macro$1.decode(is), i = coder$macro$2.decode(is), l = coder$macro$3.decode(is));
    override def getCoderArguments: java.util.List[_$1] forSome { 
      <synthetic> type _$1 <: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder[_$2] forSome { 
        <synthetic> type _$2
      }
    } = java.util.Collections.emptyList;
    override def verifyDeterministic(): _root_.scala.Unit = ()
  };
  new $anon()
}
```

```
[error] .../DefMacroCoderSpec.scala:17:56: com.github.fpopic.scalamacros.beam.Pojo does not take parameters
[error]     val coder: Coder[Pojo] = DefMacroCoder.productCoder[Pojo]
[error]                                                        ^
[error] one error found
```

Which I believe comes from [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/ContextErrors.scala#L699-L700) but don't fully understand what the compiler is trying to tell me?

Link to the full code sample can be found [here](https://github.com/fpopic/scala-code-generation-poc/blob/31a563daec9085e55beec62090a0a9e52b55d692/scala-macros/src/main/scala/com/github/fpopic/scalamacros/beam/DefMacroCoder.scala#L47-L116)
Link to CI error can be found [here](https://github.com/fpopic/scala-code-generation-poc/runs/2486161979?check_suite_focus=true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're instantiating your class is wrong:

```
${tpe.typeConstructor}(...)
```

It should be

```
new $tpe(...)
```

or if you want to do it with case class companion object's `apply` instead of plain constructor:

```
${tpe.typeSymbol.companion}(...)
```

NOTE: **type constructor** (also known as higher kinded type) has nothing to do with **class constructor**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I planned to use  `typeConstructor` to create  `Coder[F]` type and then start implicit search for it but then totally mixed those two and misplaced it.

Comment: @ghik Some people argue whether TC and HKT are the same :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246719/what-is-a-higher-kinded-type-in-scala