# Generic function that accepts two monadic values and returns a single monadic value

Tags: scala, haskell, generics, monads

I've the written the following Haskell function which accepts two monadic values and combine them into a single monadic value (it's just to illustrate the degree of genericity (or generic-ness) that Haskell type-system could support).

```hs
combine x y = do
  a <- x
  b <- y
  return (a, b)
```

and I tested it with three different monads:

```hs
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ combine (Just 10) (Just 20)  -- Maybe a
  putStrLn $ show $ combine [100] [10, 20]       -- [] a
  a <- combine getLine getLine                   -- IO a
  putStrLn $ show a
```

And it [works great](http://rextester.com/UIOI66432) as expected. Now, I want to know if Scala's type-system could allow me to write the above function without compromising the genericity. But I don't know Scala enough (though I wish to explore it). So could anyone help me convert this code into Scala?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1992532/2303202 ?

Comment: @max630: Does that help here, in any way? Could you post an answer if it does so?

Comment: @Nawaz, when we think of `f` as an applicative functor (all monads are applicative functors), it's common to call values of type `f a` "actions", whether or not they actually "do something". Your `combine` function can be made to work for *all* applicative functors: `combine :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b); combine = liftA2 (,)`. Indeed, even `Applicative` is slightly more than you need. You could get away with `combine :: Apply f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b); combine xs ys = (,) <$> xs <.> ys`. But `Apply` isn't a superclass of `Applicative`, so in practice that may not be wise.

Comment: @dfeuer Could you provide a link to `Apply`? The closest thing I can find is PureScript's `Apply` class, but that doesn't define `<.>`.

Comment: @chepner, it's [in `Data.Functor.Bind`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.2.2/docs/Data-Functor-Bind.html#t:Apply) in `semigroupoids`. PureScript makes it a superclass of `Applicative`, so it doesn't need that oddly-named operator. I forgot about `liftF2`, which is obviously the better method to use here.

Comment: I don't know scala, but you aren't you basicaly asking can you call monadic method generically? If you could, your `compose(x, y)` would be written as someting like `bind(x, a => bind (y, b => pure((a, b))))`

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks; odd that Hoogle doesn't show anything for `Apply` or `<.>`, but you can search for `semigroupoids` itself.

Comment: @chepner The haskell.org Hoogle only searches in packages bundled with GHC, unless you specify the extra package(s) (eg. `liftF2 +semigroupoids`). Stackage Hoogle and Hayoo tend to be more helpful when you don't know where to look for.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is the equivalent:

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

def combine[T, F[_]: Monad](fa: F[T], fb: F[T]) = for {
    a <- fa
    b <- fb
  } yield (a, b)
```

Where `Monad` is from a library (cats or scalaz).

`combine(Option(10), Option(20))` produces `Some((10,20))` and `combine(List(100), List(10, 20))` produces `List((100,10), (100,20))`.

EDIT: The above version is over-constrained, since it requires the two argument types to be the same.  `def combine[A, B, F[_]: Monad](fa: F[A], fb: F[B])` fixes that.

Comment: That [does not seem to compile](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KQAz7HTQSlaRxLCzY8sL6A), saying `map` and `flatMap` not a member of type parameter `F[T]`. :|

Comment: @Nawaz you need to include the cats library (or another one that provides a monad typeclass).  Monad is not a concept from the standard scala library.

Comment: Added the imports for cats.

Answer (score 3):

Your `combine` function is equivalent to the Scala code

```
for { a <- x; b <- y } yield (a,b)
```

So you might try defining a function:

```
def combine[M[_],A,B](x: M[A], y: M[B]): M[(A,B)] = 
    for { a <- x; b <- y } yield (a,b)
```

And the compiler will complain that `flatMap` is not a member of `M[A]` and `map` is not a member of `M[B]`.

The thing with `for` is that it is a bit of compiler magic that will accept any type that implements functions called `map`, `flatMap`, and `withFilter`. This is in contrast to Haskell in which we can add (or let the compiler infer) a `Monad` constraint to let `do` notation work.

To expand on the answer @JoePallas gave, it is possible to make this work. In fact, the following implementation is essentially how GHC implements typeclasses. The `cats` and `scalaz` libraries provide all this stuff for you, but this is how the sausage is made:

First define the interface we need:

```
trait For[M[_]] {
    def map[A,B](ma: M[A], f: A => B): M[B]
    def flatMap[A,B](ma: M[A],f: A => M[B]): M[B]
    def withFilter[A](ma: M[A],q: A => Boolean): M[A]
}
```

(I'm using the name `For` and using a slightly different interface than `Monad`.)

Then we provide an implicit implementation of this trait *for every data type we want to support*. Here's an example for `Option`:

```
implicit val optionFor = new For[Option] {
  def map[A,B](ma: Option[A], f: A => B): Option[B] = ma.map(f)
  def flatMap[A,B](ma: Option[A],f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = ma.flatMap(f)
  def withFilter[A](ma: Option[A],q: A => Boolean): Option[A] = ma.withFilter(q).map(a => a)
}
```

Then we provide an implicit conversion to a type that can apply these operations:

```
implicit class ForOps[M[_], A](val ma: M[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit m: For[M]): M[B] = m.map(ma,f)
  def flatMap[B](f: A => M[B])(implicit m: For[M]): M[B] = m.flatMap(ma, f)
  def withFilter(q: A => Boolean)(implicit m: For[M]): M[A] = m.withFilter(ma,q)
}
```

And finally, we can define `combine`:

```
def combine[M[_]: For, A, B](ma: M[A], mb: M[B]): M[(A, B)] =
  for { a <- ma; b <- mb } yield (a, b)
```

---

The syntax

```
def f[T: TC] = ???
```

is sugar for

```
def f[T](implicit unutterableName: TC[T]) = ???
```

An `implicit` argument list, if not given explicitly at the call site, will be automatically filled in by searching for values/functions with the correct types, as long as those are themselves `implicit`. In this case, we look for a proof that `M` is a monad. In the body, this value is `implicit`, and it has no name to access it. Implicit search can still find it. `ForOps` allows the 3 `for` operations to automagically appear on the values by using that `Monad`.

---

This is really an explicit version of how GHC implements typeclasses. In the simplest case of no optimization:

```hs
class Applicative m => Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

compiles to

```hs
data Monad m = Monad {
  monadSubApplicative :: Applicative m
  return :: forall a. a -> m a
  (>>=) :: forall a. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
}
```

and

```hs
instance Monad [] where
  return = _
  (>>=) = _
```

becomes

```hs
monadList :: Monad []
monadList = Monad {
    monadSubApplicative = applicativeList
  , return = _
  , (>>=) = _
}
```

You will often hear the word "dictionary" be used to describe the underlying data type and values. And `combine` is

```hs
combine :: Monad m -> m a -> m b -> m (a, b)
combine (Monad _ return (>>=)) ma mb = ma >>= \a -> mb >>= \b -> return (a, b)
```

However, GHC applies a bunch of restrictions to the system that makes it more predictable and performs more optimization. Scala sacrifices this to allow the programmer to perform more interesting acrobatics.

For good measure, an instance like this:

```hs
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { unCompose :: f (g a) }
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
  fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose $ fmap (fmap f) fga
```

would be done like this in Scala (using an `implicit def`, not a `val`):

```scala
trait Functor[F[_]] { def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B] }
final case class Compose[F[_], G[_], A](val get: F[G[A]]) extends AnyVal
object Compose {
  // you usually put these implicits in the associated companions
  // because implicit search is picky about where it looks
  implicit def functor[F[_], G[_]](implicit
    functorF: Functor[F],
    functorG: Functor[G]
    // type lambda: use a type projection on a refinement type
    // to create an anonymous type-level function
    // it's universally accepted as a horrendous abuse of syntax
    // you can use the kind-projector plugin to avoid writing them (directly)
  ) : Functor[({type L[X] = Compose[F, G, X]})#L]
    = new Functor[({type L[X] = Compose[F, G, X]})#L] {
      override def map[A, B](cfga: Compose[F, G, A])(f: A => B): Compose[F, G, B] =
        Compose(functorF.map(cfga.get) { ga => functorG.map(ga)(f) })
    }
}
```

Making all this stuff explicit is a bit ugly, but it works quite well.

Comment: *"And the compiler will complain that flatMap is not a member of M[A] and map is not a member of M[B]."*... So, what you've written will not actually compile and run?

Comment: The first line is fine (just the `for` comprehension on its own). The definition of the function `combine` as written here will not work.

Comment: If you would compare this to the implementation of Haskell's runtime environment that supports all those monadic `do`-comprehensions with type inference, it would'nt look that "insane". The difference is that in Scala, you can write both the library defining all the `Monad`-traits, *and* implement the "runtime system" that is needed to support it in the same library, without any tweaks to the compiler, the runtime system (hidden from the user), or any compiler plugins. Scala Cats is somewhat of an FP-DSL built on top on Scala, with interpreters written in Scala. That's a different approach.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I agree that Scala's implicits are strictly more powerful than Haskell's typeclasses. However, there is no runtime support for `do` notation in Haskell. It's a syntactic transformation just like Scala's `for` that happens at compile time. The different is just that `do` transforms your syntax using functions that belong to a particular interface which is part of the standard library.

Comment: @user2297560 Yes, `Monad` is embedded much deeper in Haskell's standard library. What I meant by the runtime system support: if Haskell's runtime system didn't provide special support for all those "interact-with-the-world-IO-monads", then you couldn't do anything with it. On the other hand, even though Scala does not mention any monads anywhere in the spec, and does not treat any IO-monads specially, you can still build the whole monadic-applicative zoo from scratch, because Scala has access to all the lower level IO and multithreading and what not.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Haskell has full type erasure, so there is no IO type at runtime; it's a feature of the type system to separate pure computations from those that interact with the world. And I'd argue this is a good thing: you can't add purity to Scala with a library.

Comment: @user2297560 I'm not talking about type erasure. I'm saying that the interactions with `stdin` and `stdout` for the instances of IO that must be implemented somewhere in the runtime system, because they fundamentally cannot be implemented as a pure function from the Haskell itself: there must be something in the runtime system that interprets instances of IO, and does some *actual* IO, instead of just composing pure plans. Haskell's monads rely on runtime system support. Scala's monads rely on nothing, they can implement their interactions with `stdin` and `stdout` themselves.

Comment: @user2297560 But yeah, you cannot add purity as a library. You instead have to define each time what is "pure enough" for a particular application, and then stick to conventions and self-discipline, with some support from type system. Again, I can't say whether it's "good" or "bad", it's different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168951/discussion-between-user2297560-and-andrey-tyukin).

Answer (score 0):

In functional programming (and programming in general) it is good practice to use the least powerful abstraction you can find. In the example you gave, you actually don't need the power of a monad. The combine function is liftA2 from the applicative type class. Example:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Applicative
z= Just 1
y= Just 2
liftA2 (,) z y
> Just (1,2)
```

In Scala you have something similar. An example from the Scalaz library which uses the same abstraction:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
(Option(1) |@| Option(2))(Tuple2.apply)
> res3: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1, 2))
```

The reason you don't need the monad abstraction is that the values are independent of each other.

Comment: Does your scala example work for other monadic values? Can we wrap that in a function to reuse it with other monadic values?

Comment: This example works for each type which has an Applicative instance.

Comment: @Nawaz My scalaz is somewhat rusty, but I guess it should be something like `def foo[A, B, F[_] : Applicative](a: F[A], b: F[B]): F[(A, B)] = (a |@| b)(Tuple2.apply)`, so, yes, of course, you can pack it in a function. Again, you would have to write out the `Applicative` explicitly.